# How can I run in R the same script from a parent folder to all sub-sub folders

Tags: r, recursion, subdirectory, rscript

I have a project folder that contains 10 subfolders (one per sampled station) and each station has several folders (so sub-sub folder from the project) with data for different sampling dates.

[image]

I need to run the same script for all the "species.txt" files for all dates and stations.

I found this next code in another post that helped me run the script for the first level subfolders but I do not know how can I make it run for the next level.

```
parent.folder <- "C:/R_Files/Data/ProjectIO"
sub.folders <- list.dirs(parent.folder, recursive=TRUE)[-1]
r.scripts <- file.path(parent.folder, "speciesnames.r")
# Run scripts in sub-folders 
for(i in sub.folders) {
  setwd(i)
  source(r.scripts)
}
```

Could any give me a hint?

Thank you

SG

Comment: Your question is too broad. Unfortunately we don't know the folder structure and we can't reproduce your example. Judging from your description, you have data files in sub folders. If so, I recommend, loading them all in one R script and then do your analysis.

Comment: `list.dirs(parent.folder)` gives you a list of every directory and sub-directory. Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: What you would to do with those sampling dates? If `speciesnames.R` contain the codem, and you have to call every sampling data files from subfolders, I would consider `list.files(path = parrent.folder, pattern = ".dat", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)`

Comment: Hi,  i have updated it with a schema on how the files are distributed maybe that explains a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what operation is run by the 1:n script, but here is a way to find all files called `species.txt`, import the .txt-files (the code assumes its in the .txt-files that can be read into a df) in any number of sub-folders.

The parent-script is sourced n times, where n = number of files imported into `species_list`.

```
parent_script = "parent.R"

vector_species = list.files(full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = "species\\.txt$")

specist_list <- map(vector_species, rio::import)

lapply(specist_list, function(x){
  species <<- x
  
  source(parent_script)
  })
```

The `parent.R`-script uses the species-object created in `lapply`. `<<-` makes the species object available outside the namespace of the lapply function.

```
# parent.R
head(species)
```

Note: In my setup, the working directory is relative to the root of the project folder.

Comment: Hi thanks, But I only want one script located in the parent folder that targets all the files called "species.txt"

Comment: Do you have one (1:n) script that is to run n number of times for each `species.txt`, or do you one script for each of the `species.txt`-files (n:n)?

Comment: The first one, I have one script to run a number of times for each species.txt

Comment: I have edited my answer. I hope you find it helpful.